# Enter key press on react applications

Tags: reactjs, forms

In my react application, I want to login and register, when user clicks on the login button. What is the better approach here, Coding to enter key press or use of a submit button instead of a button?

If we use a submit button, we have to preventDefault behaviour for the form submit. So, is it a good way to code for ENTER key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple fields in your form people might press the enter key between fields. I think it's better to stick to the submit approach. Makes your site more accessible if you stick to established, expected patterns and use HTML semantics. For example, encapsulating everything in a `<form/>` component and having an onsubmit action will make it easier for screen readers to decipher what is going on.